# How to add a image after input value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to create a beatiful js validation and incorrect markers is label must be inside inputs fields after value. Unfortunately, I still haven't got any idea how to realize this feature, need help.

ps must work in ie8+, opera 11 and in other normal browsers.

**UPDATE**

I need a custom validation, beacause designers want more beauty.

Comment: Do you have a question or do you just want someone to do it for you?

Comment: I would like to see a validation plugin that *can't* be customized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you use the Jquery Validation, avaliable [here](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/)

Read also this tutorial on best practices for form validation: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/07/07/web-form-validation-best-practices-and-tutorials/

Answer (score 1):

[Spry Validation](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/spry/articles/textfield_overview/index.html) might be useful for you? It will validate on submit. Do you want your script to validate inline?

Also, with that rep, you should at least be able to ask a decent question by now.

Comment: Much count of js validation useful for me and reqired in html5 inputs too, but our designer thinks, that there are sucks :-(